# write_history_file("pyHistory"): 'str' object has no attribute 'mode'

Tags: python, windows, conda, command-history

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47595405/2153235) on writing the Python command history to a file, which relies on the *readline* module and the *write_history_file* function therein.  I have to account for differences in using the Conda prompt on Windows 10, which is just the CMD prompt with environment variables set fo Conda.  For this use case there is no history file in c:\User.Name, which is typically the case.  Additionally, I need [*pyreadline3*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51964654/2153235).

Here is how I found the "module path" to *write_history_file* in *pyreadline3*:

```
from pprint import pprint
import inspect, pyreadline3
pprint(inspect.getmembers(pyreadline3.Readline))

   <...snip...>
   ('write_history_file',
    <function BaseReadline.write_history_file at 0x000001D67D83D280>)]^M^[[25l
   <...snip...>
```

There are some puzzling terminal-oriented control characters because I used Cygwin's Bash and `typescript` to launch Conda (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76520838/2153235)), but the "path" is shown to be *BaseReadline.write_history_file*.  I got the syntax of *write_history_file* from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47595405/2153235).  Here is how I used it, resulting in an "AttributeError":

```
>>> pyreadline3.BaseReadline.write_history_file('pyHistory')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\.conda\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyreadline3\rlmain.p y",
             line 180, in write_history_file
    self.mode._history.write_history_file(filename)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

I get the same AttributeError even if I adorn the file name `pyHistory` with double-quotations.  The only thing I can find on the above AttributeError error is [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54969871/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-mode) but it doesn't seem to be applicable because the answer there is that the wrong type of argument is being supplied.

**How else can track down the cause of this error?**

For me, the simpler the better.  I am trying to access a live command history because it helps me experiment and get started with Python (and Conda), coming from a Matlab where the history is always available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyreadline3` and `readline` are two different modules. The answer you copied that code from is for [`readline.write_history_file`](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline/blob/master/pyreadline/rlmain.py#L167), which takes a single string as an argument.

You're trying to call [`pyreadline3.BaseReadline.write_history_file`](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline/blob/master/pyreadline/rlmain.py#L167), which is a different function. In fact, it's actually not a function, it's a method. So when you try to run `BaseReadline.write_history_file("...")`, you're passing the string `"..."` as the instance object `self`. Hence why this explodes catastrophically.

To use that method correctly, you need to start by creating an instance of `BaseReadline` (or really, of an appropriate subclass, like `Readline`). Then you can invoke the method on that instance:

```
r = pyreadline3.Readline()
r.write_history_file("./pyHistory.txt")
```

Comment: I just added details from `getmembers` to my posted question. It shows `write_history_file` as a function. I think it's a matter of terminology, i.e., "function" includes "member functions" as per C++ terminology from the 90's. I also found that I can get help with `help(pyreadline3)` and `help(pyreadline3.BaseReadline)`. However, I wonder if there is any syntactical way to discern between a nested module vs. a class within a module (`BaseReadline` is shown as a class rather than a module). Or are they the same?

Comment: I found also your code creates `pyHistory.txt` , but has a size of 0 bytes. This remains true even though I issued commands such as `r.get_history_length()` (yielding 100), `"dog"`, `'cat'`, various help commands, and reissuing `r.write_history_file("./pyHistory.txt")`. I was wondering whether there is anything stunningly obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: After some troubleshooting, I found that `r.get_current_history_length() returns 0`.  This differs from `r.get_history_length()`, which returns 100.  The former (0) is the number of commands stored whereas the latter (100) is the maximum number of commands that are storable.  This explanation is from `help(r)`.  Essentially, commands are not being stored in the history.

Comment: I've posted my trials and tribulations as their own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76570300/conda-on-windows-10-python-commands-not-stored-in-command-history)